# Implementing flock() with POSIX or SysV Semaphores

Tags: perl, unix, semaphore, flock

I would like to use exclusive/shared, both blocking and non-blocking [**atomic**](http://wiki.osdev.org/Atomic_operation) locks like these found in `flock()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(:flock);

open my $fh, ">", "/tmp/lockf" or die $!;

# one of LOCK_EX, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB, LOCK_SH, LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB
my $lock_mode = LOCK_EX;
flock($fh, $lock_mode) or die $!;
```

How can this functionality be achieved using semaphores?

Comment: @PP is there some example for non-blocking mutex/lock?

Comment: What are you trying to do (I'd like to avoid an X-Y-Problem here). `flock` only works between processes. What do you need to synchronize? Processes, Threads, Coroutines? Do I read your question correctly that you want to synchronize processes with something that has a semaphore interface? Counting or binary semaphores?

Comment: @amon binary semaphores (although there can be many shared locks at the same time), and yes I want to synchronize processes.

Comment: Does [IPC::Semaphore::Concurrency](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Semaphore::Concurrency) look useful?

Comment: @amon tnx, I'll take a look at it. It would be nice not to depend on file system though.

Comment: @Сухой27 The lock has to have some shareable "key" - technically IPC::Semaphore::Concurrency could be modified to allow anonymous semaphores but those can only be passed on to children processes using fork. Since it wasn't anything like my use case when I wrote it I never implemented it. Note that you can always use your own script name as a "lock file".